# Create new element in cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

What is the best way to create a new element in cheerio?

May be:

```
cheerio.load('<li>something in here!</li>')
```

or

```
$('li', '<li>bla, bla, bla, ...</li>')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `load` nor the context string actually create HTML. They serve as a starting point for creating a virtual DOM.

[Refer to the Manipulation section in the documentation](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#append) for methods of injecting into the DOM. Namely, the following methods are provided for injection:

- `append`
- `appendTo`
- `prepend`
- `prependTo`
- `after`
- `insertAfter`
- `before`
- `insertBefore`
- `replaceWith`
- `html`
- `wrap`